# How to Call an expression list in a Block of Mathematica

Tags: list, expression, wolfram-mathematica, call, block

Here is a block function:

```
ublock[UU_]:=Block[{tt},U[z_]:=UU[[1]];
tt=2 U[z]+3 U'[z]+U''[z]];
UU:={z^2,z,Sin[z]};
ublock[UU]
```

Where `tt,U[z]` are temp variables, and I want to get the result:

`2*z^2+6z+2`

but the result is:

`2z^2`

why the results of `U'[z]` and `U''[z]` lost?

How to get the result I want?

Comment: Should be moved to [mathematica.stackexchange.com/](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I ask question in stackoverflow, can you let me know how to move this question to the right place? Thank you.

Comment: Stack exchange is a network of Q&A websites which are split into domain of interest: Stack Overflow for code, Ask DIfferent for Apple-related issues, etc. You can find all the sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Create an account on matematica.stackexchange and re-ask your question there. [More infos on moving questions...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: @Nino Filiu, Please help me move the topic to  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com  in order to benefit the people met the similar problem. I, myself, certainly can re-ask the question in the domain of mathematica, but am afraid of losing the process of solving the problem including the question and whole answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some evaluations help

```
UU := {z^2, z, Sin[z]};
ublock[UU_] := Evaluate@Block[{tt},
    U[z_] := Evaluate@UU[[1]];
    tt = 2 U[z] + 3 U'[z] + U''[z]];
ublock[UU]
```

> 2 + 6 z + 2 z^2

But for more flexibility

```
Clear[U, UU, ublock]

ublock[UU_] := Block[{tt},
   U[z_] := 0;
   DownValues[U] = ReplacePart[DownValues[U], {1, 2} -> UU[[1]]];
   tt = 2 U[z] + 3 U'[z] + U''[z]]

UU := {z^2, z, Sin[z]}

ublock[UU]
```

> 2 + 6 z + 2 z^2

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved my proposed problem perfectly. I, however, have a further question: why can I **not** run another line code after your provided program? For example, run `UU1 := {Sin[z], z^3, Exp[z]}; ublock[UU1]` after your code, it will give the same result but the UU1 is not UU. Thank you again.

Comment: @liklee OK. It”s a good question, but I’ll have to get back to it later. At a party. 

Comment: @likelee Because of the `Evaluate`. The solution by @Alan avoids `Evaluate` and will work for different arguments.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi, Alan. Because the `tt` expression is derived from a lot of codes, the form of `tt` cannot be changed, namely, U[z]'s derivation have to be kept ` U'[z]` or `U''[z]` rather than other form. So, I cannot accept **Alan**'s answer, thanks **Alan** and **you**. I have to wait for the best solution of my problem.

Comment: @Chris Degnen, Thank you very much for your proposed excellent solution, you solved my further problem perfectly.  It's regret I have no reputation score present to you because I'm a freshman in stackoverflow, only to thank you again to express my gratitude.

Comment: @likelee No problem. Thanks for the accept. If you have Mathematica questions in the future you should ask here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Chris Degnen , I've sent a letter to you, check it please.

Comment: @likelee Yes, I received it and had a look.  I will check it out again later.

Answer (score 0):

```
ublock[UU_] := Module[{tt}, U = UU[[1]];
   tt = 2 U + 3 D[U, z] + D[U, {z, 2}]]
```

or better yet

```
ublock[UU_] := With[{U = UU[[1]]}, 2 U + 3 D[U, z] + D[U, {z, 2}]]
```

Comment: The answer you posted is good, thank you. but, **(1)**  the `tt` expression is derived from a lot of codes(the derivation process was skipped in order to simplified the question), the form of `tt` cannot be changed, namely, U[z]'s derivation have to be kept ` U'[z]` or U''[z] rather than other form. **(2)** Your answer similar to Chris Dedgnen's can not be used to solve `ublock[UU]` and  `ublock[UU1]` at the same time. Do you have alternative solutions that can solve my further problem?  I will have to wait for the proper solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
UU = {z^2, z, Sin[z]};
ublock[UU_] := Evaluate@Block[{tt}, U[z_] = UU[[1]];
    tt = 2 U[z] + 3 U'[z] + U''[z]];
ublock[UU]

(* 2 + 6 z + 2 z^2 *)
```